# What will be the value of $\int_\gamma x\cdot n(x) \, ds(x).$

Tags: calculus, analytic-geometry, surface-integrals

> Let $x=(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2$, $n(x)$ denote the unit outward normal to the ellipse $\gamma$ whose equation is given by $\frac{x^2} 4 +\frac{y^2} 9 = 1$ at the point $x$ on it.
>
> What will be the value of $\displaystyle\int_{\gamma}x\cdot n(x)\,ds(x)\text{ ?}$

Comment: Questions posted here should not be phrased in language suitable for assigning homework. One could wonder if you copied a question without understanding it, so that no actual question is present in your own mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Use the planar version of the [Divergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem):
$$\int_{\partial D} (v_1,v_2) \cdot n \, ds=\int_D \left(\frac{\partial v_1}{\partial x} +\frac{\partial v_2}{\partial y} \right)\, dxdy.$$
In particular take a look to this [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem#Examples).

Comment: How to cal calculate unit outward normal vector?

Comment: @Pedrick Serre  You need not calculate the outward normal. By the way, your notation $x=(x,y)$ is confusing. What is the given vector field in your exercise? $(x,y)$? $(x,0)$? $(0,x)$?

Comment: I know I dont require it. Just i want to know. $x=(x,y)$

Comment: @Pedrick Serre Take the gradient of $\frac{x^2} 4 +\frac{y^2} 9$ and normalize.
 See the answer here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1673378/determining-the-normal-of-an-ellipse?rq=1