# Find slopes of tangents to a non-centered rotated ellipse

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, tangent-line

Let's take from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426150/what-is-the-general-equation-of-the-ellipse-that-is-not-in-the-origin-and-rotate) the equation for a rotated ellipse that is not centered at the origin:

$$\frac {((x-h)\cos(A)+(y-k)\sin(A))^2}{a^2}+\frac{((x-h) \sin(A)-(y-k) \cos(A))^2}{b^2}=1,$$

where $h, k$ and $a, b$ are the shifts and semi-axis in the $x$ and $y$ directions respectively and $A$ is the angle measured from $x$ axis.

I have also the general equation of a line:

$$ y = \alpha + \beta x $$

Assuming that $\alpha = 0$, how can I find the slope $\beta$ so that the line $y$ is a tangent of the ellipse? There should be two of them.

**EDIT**: I found also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/171936/how-do-i-get-a-tangent-to-a-rotated-ellipse-in-a-given-point?rq=1), but I don't understand the parameterization. It's basically the same question as mine, but I don't understand why the ellipse is defined by a system of equations and not a single equation; I also don't know what is $t$; it would be helpful if someone could just switch the parameterizations because the question seems to already have an answer.

Comment: The answer seems to be $$\beta=\frac{C\pm \sqrt{D}}{B},$$ where $$B=h^2+\left(\cos ^2A-1\right)\,b^2-\cos ^2A\,a^2$$
$$C=h\,k+\cos A\,\sin A\,b^2-\cos A\,\sin A\,a^2$$
$$D=\left(\left(1-\cos ^2A\right)\,b^2+\cos ^2A\,a^2
 \right)\,k^2+\left(2\,\cos A\,\sin A\,b^2-2\,\cos A\,\sin A\,a^2
 \right)\,h\,k+\left(\cos ^2A\,b^2+\left(1-\cos ^2A\right)\,a^2
 \right)\,h^2-a^2\,b^2.$$ I found it by using dual conics. Do you want an answer detailing this approach?

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland Thanks, this seems excellent. Please post it as an answer. I think it is already detailed enough but of course it would maybe be helpful for future readers to learn about more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recipe is to take the dual conic (with matrix the adjugate matrix to the matrix of the conic) going through the point $(-\frac1{\alpha},\frac{\beta}{\alpha})$ corresponding to $y=\alpha+\beta x$ being tangent to the conic. Writing the resulting expression as a fraction with denominator having $\alpha^2$ as a factor, setting $\alpha=0$ in the numerator gives a quadratic in $\beta.$ I can flesh it out if you want. A CAS helps.